PostgreSQL Trigger Procedures Asynchronously From Main Overall Procedure
I am currently working on building a pipeline using a PostgreSQL DB hosted by AWS RDS. In my pipeline, I have a stored procedure in PostgreSQL that is triggered by cron and used to executed other stored procedures. A summary of the procedure is below:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE <postgres_schema>.main_procedure()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
begin
    
call <postgres_schema>.procedure_one();
call <postgres_schema>.procedure_two();
call <postgres_schema>.procedure_three();

END;
$procedure$
;

I was wondering, is there a way to execute the last two of these procedures (procedure_two, and procedure_three) in parallel, or at least asynchronously? I am trying to set up a process where the main_procedure() is called, procedure_one() is executed first, then once that procedure is complete procedure_two() and procedure_three() are called at the same time and execute in the background.

@LaurenzAlbe, using dblink, it is possible to invoke asynchronous/concurrent procedures.

@JohnH That is ugly, but yes.

@LaurenzAlbe, I agree it's ugly, and I prefer external tools that are better suited to orchestrating asynchronous events; however, it can be useful approach.

The following demonstrates an approach to performing asynchronous/concurrent procedures using dblink.
Begin by installing the dblink extension (supplied with PostgreSQL):
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS dblink;

Next, we'll create three procedures to be called. For this example, they each perform the same operation; i.e. sleeping for a requested number of seconds. We could also have used a single procedure and invoked it multiple times concurrently.
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure_one(delay_in_seconds DOUBLE PRECISION) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$proc$
BEGIN
  PERFORM pg_sleep(delay_in_seconds);
END;
$proc$;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure_two(delay_in_seconds DOUBLE PRECISION) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$proc$
BEGIN
  PERFORM pg_sleep(delay_in_seconds);
END;
$proc$;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure_three(delay_in_seconds DOUBLE PRECISION) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$proc$
BEGIN
  PERFORM pg_sleep(delay_in_seconds);
END;
$proc$;

The final part of setup is to create the main procedure which will call the others:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE main_procedure () LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$proc$
DECLARE
  -- connection string
  connstr TEXT := 'hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=so_wip user=postgres';
BEGIN
  -- invoke a procedure synchronously within the current session
  CALL procedure_one(5);
  -- establish two named connections
  PERFORM dblink_connect('con1', connstr);
  PERFORM dblink_connect('con2', connstr);
  -- asynchronously invoke a procedure on each named connection
  PERFORM dblink_send_query('con1', 'CALL procedure_two(10);');
  PERFORM dblink_send_query('con2', 'CALL procedure_three(5);');
  -- disconnect the named connections
  PERFORM dblink_disconnect('con1');
  PERFORM dblink_disconnect('con2');
END;
$proc$;

Finally, call the main procedure:
CALL main_procedure();

By querying pg_stat_activity from a separate connection (or using pgAdmin's dashboard) while the procedures are running, one can see that they are indeed running concurrently. Polling the named connections, using dblink_is_busy, can be used to determine when asynchronous procedures have completed.
